# SQL update query with join and subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the values of a column to the results of a sub query. I get the error that the sub query is returning more that one row, which it should. It should be returning a column of values.

```
Update companies
set c_c_score = ( select t.summ 
              from ( select sum(case when b.hot_tip = 1 
                                     then ((@maxrank-c.rank)/(@maxrank-1)) * (b.score-3) 
                                     else 0 
                                     end) as summ
                     from companies a
                     left join table2 b
                         on a.id = b.company_id
                     left join table3 c
                         on b.table3_id = c.id
                     group by a.id ) AS t);
```

The sub query runs fine by itself.

```
    select a.id,  sum(case when b.hot_tip = 1 then ((@maxrank-c.rank)/(@maxrank-1)) * (b.score-3) else 0 end)
        from companies a
        left join table2 b
        on a.id = b.company_id
        left join table3 c
        on b.table3_id = c.id
        group by a.id;
```

Comment: Your `select t.summ` returns more than one row. Check. If they are ALWAYS the same by data integrity and query logic - add DISTINCT. If not - select one value by some method (for example, use MAX() function).

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? You tagged both, maybe accidentally? Either way you cannot assign the result of a subquery that returns more than one row (or more than one column) to a scalar. Maybe you want an `UPDATE` joining the subquery?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
Update companies c
inner join (select a.id as company_id, sum(case when b.hot_tip = 1 then ((@maxrank-c.rank)/(@maxrank-1)) * (b.score-3) else 0 end) as cc_score
from companies a
left join table2 b
on a.id = b.company_id
left join table3 c
on b.table3_id = c.id
group by a.id) x ON x.company_id = c.id
set c.c_c_score = x.cc_score;
```

Comment: `JOINing` is often better than using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Akina points out in his comment, you are not allowed to assign more than a scalar value to an attribute. Your sub-query returns something like:

```
1, 2, 3
```

which of the values should be assigned to score? I assume that what you intend to do is to correlate the outer companies table with the subselect. Is this close to what you are trying to achieve?

```
update companies a
set score = ( select sum(case when b.hot_tip = 1 
                              then ((@maxrank-c.rank)/(@maxrank-1)) * (b.score-3) 
                              else 0 
                         end) as summ
              from table2 b
              left join table3 c
                  on b.table3_id = c.id
              where a.id = b.company_id
            );
```